# Nftables "Error: Interface does not exist" after reboot

Tags: debian, systemd, nftables

at using nftables on a new virtual machine (Debian 10) I installed and configured nftables as automatic service (systemd). I use also LXC and use an additional interface (lxcbr0).

I recognized the problem that the nftables service does not start successfully after reboot. The error: `/etc/nftables.conf:56:32-39: Error: Interface does not exist`

It seems that the interface get only up after the nftables service startup:
Startup date of nftables (log output):

```
Apr 05 11:41:23 WEB01 systemd[1]: Starting nftables...
```

Startup date of the interface:

```
Apr 05 11:41:25 WEB01 ifup[397]: Waiting for lxcbr0 to get ready
```

--> 2 second delay between the startups

Is there a general solution for this or a common work around? On the wiki of nftables I did not find something like that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to change your rules in nftables like this:

- replace all occurences of `iif lxcbr0` with `iifname lxcbr0`
- replace all occurences of `oif lxcbr0` with `oifname lxcbr0`
- there are equivalent replacements for sets, I could write something about it if the ruleset was given.

The reason for this is that `iif` and `oif` expect an interface *index* rather than an interface *name*. For this, the interface must have been created before the rule referencing it. `iifname` and `oifname` check if current interfaces have one with a matching name.

More explanations about this in [this other Q/A](https://serverfault.com/questions/985158/what-is-the-different-between-iifname-and-iif-in-nftables/).

Other methods would require the synchronization with the creation of the interface: after the interface was created but before it goes up to avoid any window where there's no firewall/NAT. This would likely depend on the network manager in use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I switched from "oifname/iifname" to "oif/iif" but without success. Then I checked for the systemd config and saw the following line: "Before=network-pre.target shutdown.target". I thought this is not good and added and "After" section with "After=network-online.target". Now it works! Do you think that could be the final solution or is there any concerns about this? I ask because of the "Before" line. This line says that "network-pre" should start after the nftables service. Right?

Comment: I don't have enough information to know what was your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue using `define` on a `bridge` interface e.g:

```
define PRIV_IF = br0
```

(so the `iifname` / `oifname` trick did not work)

Adding an override for `nftables` fixed it:

```
systemctl edit nftables --drop-in=any-name
```

Add to the console editor that opens up **near the top**:

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

& `systemctl daemon-reload`